# Choquet's theorem (Exercise 7 of Chapter 13 in Lax's functional analysis)

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a problem with Exercise 7 of Chapter 13 in Lax's functional analysis. The definitions in Exercise 7 comes from Theorem 5. I post both of them below.  My attempt is to get an sequence of points $v_n\in K_e$ and $v_n\rightarrow v$ in $\bar{K}_e$, so that for each $v_n$, we have a measure $m_n$, according to Theorem 5. But I don't know how to prove $m_n$ converge to some measure $m$ and $m(v)=0$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think your attempted method will not lead to a proof of Exercise 7.  In fact $\overline{K_e} \subseteq K$ so the integral (10) exists representing $v$ by Theorem 5.  The other part would be: using the fact that $v$ is not an extreme point of $K$, show that, among all measures $m$ representing $v$, at least one has the property $m(\{v\}) = 0$.

Comment: I got the first part just now. Could u show more details about how to prove $m(v)=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do we know?  $v \in\overline{K_e}\subseteq K$ but $v \notin K_e$ ... that is what we have to work with.

$v$ is not an extreme point of $K$.  That is:
There exist $v_1, v_2 \in K$, $v_1 \ne v_2$, $v = \frac{1}{2}(v_1+v_2)$.  Note also $v_1 \ne v \ne v_2$.  By Theorem 5, there exist probability measures $m_1, m_2$ on $\overline{K_e}$ that represent $v_1, v_2$, respectively:
$$
v_1 = \int_{\overline{K_e}} e\;dm_1(e),\qquad
v_2 = \int_{\overline{K_e}} e\;dm_2(e)
$$
Since $v \ne v_1$ we have $m_1(\{v\}) < 1$; similarly $m_2(\{v\}) < 1$.  We can define probability measure $m_3$ on $\overline{K_e}$ by
$$
m_3 = \frac{1}{2}(m_1+m_2)
$$
so that $m_3$ represents $v$:

> $$
> \int_{\overline{K_e}} e\;d m_3(e) =
> \frac{1}{2}\int_{\overline{K_e}} e\;d m_1(e)+
> \frac{1}{2}\int_{\overline{K_e}} e\;d m_2(e)
> =\frac{1}{2}\;v_1 + \frac{1}{2}\;v_2 = v
> $$

There is also probability measure $m_4$, the Dirac measure at $v$, which represents $v$:

> $$
> v = \int_{\overline{K_e}} e\;d m_4(e)
> $$

The measure $m$ we want will be a linear combination of $m_3$ and $m_4$.  It has to be a probability measure, it has to vanish on $\{v\}$, and
it has to represent $v$.

Write $\alpha = m_3(\{v\})$.  We have $0 \le \alpha < 1$.  Define (signed) measure $m$ by
$$
m = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}m_3 - \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}m_4
$$
Then $m$ is a nonnegative measure.

> If $A \subseteq K$ then
>   take two cases: $v \in A$ and $v \notin A$.  If $v \notin A$, then
>   $$
> m(A) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}m_3(A)+0 \ge 0 .
> $$
>   If $v \in A$, then $m_3(A) \ge m_3(\{v\}) = \alpha$ and thus
>   $$
> m(A) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}m_3(A) - \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}m_4(A)
> \ge \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\;\alpha - \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\;1 = 0
> $$

And $m$ is a probability measure

> $$
> m(\overline{K_e}) = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}m_3(\overline{K_e}) 
> - \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}m_4(\overline{K_e})
> = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\;1 - \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\;1 = 1
> $$

And $m$ vanishes on $\{v\}$:

> $$
> m(\{v\}) = 
> \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\;m_3(\{v\}) - \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\;m_4(\{v\}) =
> \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\;\alpha - \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\;1 = 0
> $$

And $m$ represents $v$

> $$
> \int_{\overline{K_e}} e\;dm(e) =
> \frac{1}{1-\alpha}\int_{\overline{K_e}} e\;dm_3(e) -
> \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\int_{\overline{K_e}} e\;dm_4(e) =
> \frac{1}{1-\alpha}v - \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}v = v
> $$